# How to set Load Balancers onto EC2 (installed Apache with SSL)?

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb

I am running several EC2 instances behind ELB load balancers.
Can I insert my SSL certificate into Apache server without insert my cert into the load balancers?

How should I set for the load balancers? Change the rules of security groups or something else?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. That's possible.

To do the same, at the Load Balancer level, use `TCP` as the Load Balancer Protocol instead of HTTPS. Use the port `443` as Load Balancer port as well as the Instance Port.

If you use the HTTPS then you have to provide with the SSL details, but simply passing it through with TCP will work perfectly.

I am doing the same in my setup.

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from the ELB docs [here](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/)...

> Elastic Load Balancing supports SSL termination at the Load Balancer,
>   including offloading SSL decryption from application instances,
>   centralized management of SSL certificates, and encryption to back-end
>   instances with optional public key authentication.

So the best option will be to place your SSL certs there, as long as you want to set that certificate to all your cluster.

@leo

Answer (score 0):

installing SSL cert to each web server worked for me. i was having a multiple websites hosted in web servers behind a load balance server. may be links [ssl cert in cluster](https://serverfault.com/questions/115529/sharing-ssl-certificates-in-a-cluster) and [enter link description here](http://forums.comodo.com/ssl-certificate/ssl-certificate-for-cluster-behind-load-balancer-t84262.0.html) might help you, because i got a proper direction after going through both these. I hope in your case,you have to use of `Amazon elastic ip service`